# Is it possible to set a className on custom react components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Let's say I have a simple component like this:

```
class SimpleComponent extends React.Component
{
    render() { return <p>Some text</p> }
}
```

Is it possible to add a `className` to `SimpleComponent` or is this constrained to HTML DOM elements only?

For example:

```
var mySimpleComponent = <SimpleComponent className="myComp"/>
```

The reason I would like to do this is so that I can style the elements inside my custom component like this:

```
.myComp > p {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: create an external div before the p tag and give it a className of .myComp

Comment: Is this the only solution? I hoped I wouldn't have to create enclosing div elements for all my components

Answer (score 62, accepted):

You can, but you should propagate the prop to the inner component. If not, it doesn't know about it.

```
class SimpleComponent extends React.Component
{
    render() { return <p className={this.props.className}>Some text</p> }
}
```

To make the CSS query you want to accomplish, then you should create the `div` inside your component.

```
class SimpleComponent extends React.Component
{
    render() { return <div className={this.props.className}><p>Some text</p></div> }
}
```

Comment: I would suggest below code achieve the end goal.   

    class SimpleComponent extends React.Component
    {
        render() { return <div className={this.props.className}><p>Some text</p></div> }
    }

Wrap a DIV tag around your desired HTML markup and use the className prop you have passed through your custom component.

Comment: Right, I focused too much in the reason why it didn't work. It should be `<div className={this.props.className}><p>Some text</p></div>`.