# Issue with tailwind css gradient

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I am trying to apply gradient to my nav links but it is not showing any results.
This is my code

```
<NavLink className="block p-4 pr-0 mr-3 bg-gradient-to-br from-purple-500 
  to-indigo-500 rounded-tr-full rounded-br-full text-textPrimary 
  hover:text-white text-xl" to="/dashboard">
    <i class="fas fa-laptop-house mr-3"></i>
    Dashboard
</NavLink>
```

I am using tailwind css and react

Comment: If you inspect the element are styles being applied to the classes?

Comment: Yes styles are applied to the elements. All the styles working fine except gradient

Comment: Is there something else that applies background color? It's hard to troubleshoot without seeing any of that.

Comment: If I apply background color to the nav item, it works fine but the gradient is not working. My code is correct or not ??

Comment: Your code seems to be correct. [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ZachHaber/pen/yLJWoKV)
Is there something in the NavLink component that is applying a style? Are you using an ancient version of tailwind css? Could you post a running example that shows the behavior you are having?

Comment: Yesterday, I upgraded to v2.0

Comment: There is some problem with my config file. now, it's working fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It looks like there is no color schema in your config.

Just add this to your tailwind.config.js.

```
const colors = require("tailwindcss/colors");

module.exports = {
  theme: {
    colors: {
      blue: {
        ...colors.blue,
        "your custom blue color"
      },
      green: colors.green,
      pink: colors.pink
      ...etc
    }
  },
};
```

It should work. Just pick colors you want to include in your schema. ...colors.blue will give you all shades of blue. After this, gradient with blue color should work.

Answer (score 1):

This would happen if you have customized the [tailwind.config.js](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/configuration) by ["overriding"](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#overriding-the-default-theme) related properties instead of ["extending"](https://tailwindcss.com/docs/theme#extending-the-default-theme) them.

E.g. if you have overwritten (overridden) the `colors` or `backgroundImage` property, then the original `colors` / `backgroundImage` presets are not available anymore.

E.g. the gradients *([which create CSS "background-images"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/gradient/linear-gradient))* aren't available anymore if you have added some background image like this (an overridden property):

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    theme: {
        backgroundImage: {
            'someImage': 'url("/images/some-image.png")',
        },
        extend: {
            // ...
```

You should move this customization into `extend`, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    // ...
    theme: {
        extend: {
            backgroundImage: {
                'someImage': 'url("/images/some-image.png")',
            },
            // ...
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work fine (https://play.tailwindcss.com/xnQDaASzOL).

There might be an issue with you `<NavLink />` component. Does the `className` props is goodly propagate to the inner component ?

Indeed, React does not understand `className` for custom component until you propagate it to the inner component, see this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46040808/7905936).

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your tailwind.config.js file:

```js
    module.exports = {
      content: ["./src/**/*.{js,jsx}"],
      theme: {
        extend: {
          backgroundImage: {
            'gradient-radial': 'radial-gradient(var(--tw-gradient-stops))',
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, tailwind config

```
export default {
 content: ['./index.html', './src/**/*.{js,ts,jsx,tsx}'],
 theme: {
 extend: {
   backgroundImage: {
    landing: 'linear-gradient(rgba(35, 25, 23, .48), rgba(35, 25, 23, .48)), url(/src/assets/landing.jpg)',
    interior: 'linear-gradient(rgba(35, 25, 23, .48), rgba(35, 25, 23, .48)), url(/src/assets/interior.jpg)',
    church: 'linear-gradient(rgba(35, 25, 23, .48), rgba(35, 25, 23, .48)), url(/src/assets/church.jpg)',
   },
   },
},
plugins: [],
};

<div className="bg-landing"></div>
```